# amCharts 4 - How to animate graphs after dynamic load + update of the data set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm using amCharts 4 on a page that combinate 3 graphs :
- Pie with age range of my users
- Pie with genre repartiton
- Histogram with number of orders

I've set up a system that allow to make all charts react to filters done on other charts on this page.

If I click on a age range (20-25 for example), it'll highlight the slice I clicked, get its id, and go load the content filtered with my selection for my 2 other graphs (genre/orders). Everything is working as expected on this side. I can combinate, remove my filters it works like a charm.

**My problem :**
I don't find any way to animate the load of new datas on my graphs (as it's done when graphs are first built).

**How I initiate my graphs:**

```
var chart = am4core.create("myGraph", am4charts.PieChart);
chart.dataSource.url = url_json_dataset; 
chart.dataSource.parser = new am4core.JSONParser();
```

**How I update my graphs:**

```
chart.dataSource.url = url_json_dataset_with_filters;
chart.dataSource.load();
```

I've also try to load my json outside amcharts, and force update of the dataset, and don't get better results, data load is done without any transition:

```
chart.data = my_json_array;
chart.invalidateData();
```

The animateAgain() method is documented for amCharts 3, but is not working anymore on the new version, see here : https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/showcase-various-chart-animation-effects/

Any idea on how to achieve it ?

Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Getting the same issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177366/amcharts-4-how-to-animate-graphs-after-dynamic-load-update-of-the-data-set) - Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Hi, 
I finally found how to animate again after new data loadling, here is an example for a pie chart :

`chart.invalidateRawData();
chart.dataSource.url = newurl;
chart.dataSource.load();
pieSeries.appear();`

The last line seems to do the trick!
(note in this case, I load the datas as JSON from an another script)

Live preview here : https://codepen.io/noiwid/pen/xxGaevN